# How to join Multiple tables using hibernate criteria where entity relationship is not direct?

Tags: java, sql, join, hibernate-criteria

I have three entities. those are:

```java
@Entity
public class Organization {
    @Id
    private long id;
    @Column
    private String name;
}
```

```java
@Entity
public class Book {
    @Id
    private Long id;
    @Column
    private String name;
    @ManyToOne
    private Organization organization;
}
```

```java
@Entity
public class Account  {
   @Id
   private Long id;
   @Column
   private String name;
   @ManyToOne
   private Book book;
}
```

In these three entities I would like to perform following sql:

```sql
SELECT acc.name, acc.id
FROM account acc
JOIN book b on acc.book_id = b.id
JOIN organization org on b.organization_id = org.id
WHERE org.name = 'XYZ'
```

In this case `Account` entity has no relation with the `Organization` entity directly. `Account` entity has the relation via `Book`. How can I achieve this using hibernate criteria dynamic query?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

you can do like this :

```
Criteria accountCriteria = getCurrentSession().createCriteria(Account.class,"acc");
Criteria bookCriteria =  accountCriteria .createCriteria("book","b");
Criteria orgCriteria =  bookCriteria.createCriteria("organization","org");
orgCriteria.add(Restrictions.eq("name", "XYZ"));

ProjectionList properties = Projections.projectionList();
properties.add(Projections.property("name"));
properties.add(Projections.property("id"));

accountCriteria.setProjection(properties);
accountCriteria.list();
```

Comment: where does the `criteria` comes from ? that is in line `criteria.createCriteria("book","b");` where the `criteria` object initialize ?

Answer (score 15):

Another way

```
public List<Account> getAccountListByOrgName(String name){
    return sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().createCriteria(Account.class)
                .createAlias("book", "book")
                .createAlias("book.organization", "organization")
                .add(Restrictions.eq("organization.name", name))
                .list();
}
```

Comment: With same entities, what I supposed to do if I want to return list of Organization?