# Hibernate criteria - Inner Join OR Condition

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, hibernate-criteria

I want to ignore default Join Restriction in **createAlias**. I have a OnetoOne relationship.

My Problem is Hibernate generates default restriction for the join relationship.

**Pojo**

Note : No column for diagnosticTemplate in charge table.

Charge.java

```
 @OneToOne(mappedBy = "charge")
 private DiagnosticTemplate diagnosticTemplate;
```

DiagnosticTemplate.java

```
@OneToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "charge")
@Exclude
private Charge charge;
```

**Query**

```
select 
  * 
from 
  charges c 
inner join diagnostic_template dt 
  on (dt.charge = c.id and dt.status=1) or (dt.status=0)
```

**Criteria**

```
Criteria criteria = getSession().createCriteria(Charge.class, "charge")
      .createAlias("charge.diagnosticTemplate", "diagnosticTemplate",
        JoinType.INNER_JOIN,
        Restrictions.or(
           Restriction.and(Restrictions.eqProperty("charge.id", 
                         "diagnosticTemplate.charge"), 
           Restrictions.eq("diagnosticTemplate.status",true)),
           Restrictions.eq("diagnosticTemplate.status",false)  ))
```

**Hibernate Query**

```
select 
  * 
from 
  charges c 
inner join diagnostic_template dt 
  on dt.charge = c.id and (dt.charge = c.id and dt.status=1) or (dt.status=0)
```

How to avoid this condition? or anything wrong with my relationship?

Please help..!

Answer (score 0):

When you join a `charge` with `charge.diagnosticTemplate`, it means that Hibernate will try to lookup a `DiagnosticTemplate` that is **linked** with this `charge`. Thus, the generated condition `dt.charge = c.id` does make sense.

Remember that you have define the relationship using foreign key. So, soft relation like `dt.status=0` cannot be understood by Hibernate.

If you still wish to achieve you query, you can consider joining the two instance indirectly (not using association path). Refer to [How to join Multiple table using hibernate criteria where entity relationship is not direct?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38041818/how-to-join-multiple-table-using-hibernate-criteria-where-entity-relationship-is).